# How to share postgresql tables among team members?

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a project in a team. We are using postgresql for database. Is there any way of sharing the table along with its schema i.e., the column names with my teammates. We don't want everyone to be making same tables again and again and have uniformity.

Any help would be wonderful.
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Use a central server where everybody connects to

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am a beginner, can you please tell me how to do that?